# Populate in Mongoengine, Reference Field

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Does **mongoengine** have a similar method to populate

```
db.collection.posts.findById(id).populate('user_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

day goes by but still I didn't saw anything that there is an API documentation related to `.populate()` in `mongoengine` and I chose to make my own way.

`mongoengine` is an  [Object-Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) driver, compare to `mongoose` there is already predefined function `.populate()` but if you know how OOP works it is just a piece of cake for you, here is a simple trick

```py
# .schema.author.py
class Author(Document):
   name = StringField(required=True)

# .schema.book.py
class Book(Document):
    title = StringField()
    author = ReferenceField(Author)

    def tojson(self):
        json = {
            'title ': self.title ,
            'author ': self.author,
        }
        json['author'] = self.author.name
        return json

# .route.book.py
def get(self):
    try:
       books = []
       for book in Book.objects:
          books.push(book.tojson())

       return {'status': True, 'response': books}
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

and the expected result must be populated `Author` for each `Book` object

```json
{
  "status": true,
  "response": [
     {
         "title": "<book-name>",
         "author": {
            "name": "<author-name>"
         }
     }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for populate too. it is 2023 now, but see if my code helps you in the future.

```
async def retrieve_courses():
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    populated_courses = []
    for course in courses:
        subject_ids = [str(subject.id) for subject in course.subjects]
        subjects = Subject.objects.filter(id__in=subject_ids)
        subject_dicts = [subject.to_dict() for subject in subjects]
        course_dict = course.to_dict()
        course_dict["subjects"] = subject_dicts
        populated_courses.append(course_dict)
    return convert_objectId_to_str(populated_courses)
```

The LazyReferenceField is a deferred reference that does not perform the actual database query until the referenced object is accessed. This can be useful when dealing with large collections or cases where you don't always need to fetch the referenced objects.

On the other hand, the ReferenceField performs the database query immediately when the reference is set, allowing direct access to the referenced object without an additional query.

A get() or filter() can be used to get the detailed reference objects.
The output is exactly like my favourite mongoose.

Answer (score -1):

I am not an expert in MongoEngine, but you can query like this:

`post = Posts.objects(id=id).first()`

That returns the data from that Model and it's already populated. You can access the author of the post using:

`post.author.name`

Comment: Please use comment section for suggestions!